# QStackedWidget navigation from page to page

Tags: qt

I think i'm having a fairly basic Qt problem, but i can't figure it out:

I have a QMainWindow which holds a QStackedWidget. All page widgets in there are seperate classes derived from QWidget.

So:

QMainWindow implements QStacked Window in one class.
All other pages inside the stacked widget are added classes and all have there own .ui filled with buttons and lists trough the Designer.

For navigating to different pages, inside the Mainwindow i have access to: `ui.stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(2);`

It seems i don't have access to ui.stackedWidget on another page inside the stacked widget? I have no access to the ui.stackedWidget because Ui is a private member in the mainwindow class. (auto generated by Qt - using VS addon for adding QT4 classes)

I would like to know, how can i jump to another page in the stacked widget, when clicking on a button that belongs to another page inside this widget?

Note:

All pages are added to the StackedWidget in mainWIndow's constructor:

```
ui.stackedWidget->addWidget(page1Widget);
ui.stackedWidget->addWidget(page2Widget);
// etc..
```

Example of a button click signal-slot inside page1Widget:

```
connect(ui.btnViewData, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(viewData()));

::viewData() 
{   
   // navigate to another page here. 
   // note: ui.stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(3); is not accessible here!
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that putting your connect() and viewData() functions within your QMainWindow object will solve your problem, since the main window can have access to both the signals emited by the child widgets and the QStackedWidget items.

You might need to write a Ui getter for each of your page, and then do something like

```
connect(page1Widget->getUi().btnViewData, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(viewData)));
```

hope it helps,
cheers

Comment: this actually helps with keeping the ui private in child pages and returning them trough a public getter. +1 but doesn't solve my problem: This also means i will have to handle all code related to a particular class (page1Widget, page2Widget,..) in mainWindow and therefore i would need to access all other buttons and widgets in the other class also through the getter..which obvious will make my mainWindow pretty much handle everything, including all views etc. I would like to handle pageWidged's logic in their files and only use mainWindow for navigating

Comment: I'm pretty much sure there is a Qt way of doing trough emitting signal's..but i'm not sure how.. and i don't have time to read a book..all learning is done trough a personal project. thx alot

Comment: Sure that would not be a great solution if you have loads of buttons in the widgets that need to have access to the stack, but you can still let the widgets handle everything else on their own!
The other solution I'm thinking of, is to put in every page a member variable that points to the QStackedWidget. You just have to initialize it in the main window, and then you can handle everything from the page widgets